# AVFoundation, AVCaptureMetadataOutput capturing screenshot

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture, capture-output

I am using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` in order to use iOS QRCode,barcode scanning feature. This works well, and I get the result of scanning through `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` delegate method

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
```

But I don't know how to capture the image of scanned qrcode,barcode with the data I have in this delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I have `captured image` while `scanning QRCode` like this:

**1)** Firstly add property of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput's`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
```

**2)** Add session preset in `AVCaptureSession` after initializing it

```
[self.session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
```

**3)** Now add `AVCaptureStillImageOutput's` as output in `AVCaptureSession`

```
// Prepare an output for snapshotting
self.stillImageOutput = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput new];
[self.session addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
self.stillImageOutput.outputSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG};
```

**4)** Make add below code to capture scanned image in delegate method `captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:connection`

```
 __block UIImage *scannedImg = nil;
// Take an image of the face and pass to CoreImage for detection
AVCaptureConnection *stillConnection = [self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"There was a problem");
        return;
    }

    NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

    scannedImg = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
    NSLog(@"scannedImg : %@",scannedImg);
}];
```

For **reference** use [CodeScanViewController](https://github.com/safecase123/CodeScanViewController)

**Thats it @Enjoy**